# Странная ошибка связанная с палиндромом

Tags: c

Вот код

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   char str[80]; int i,j,temp;
   const char s[2] = " ";
   char *token;
   char *token2;
   fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);

   token = strtok(str, s);
    token2=token;
    printf("\n%s",token2);
   while( token != NULL ) {

    i=0;
    j=strlen(token)-1;

        while(i<j){
            temp=token[i];
            token[i]=token[j];
            token[j]=temp;
            i++;
            j--;
                }
                printf("\n%s",token2);

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Его задание, вывести на экран все палиндромы найдены в фразе. Но программа не правильно реагирует на вот эту вставку:

```
token2=token;
```

Если я ввожу например слово: книга
Он выводит на экран:

```
книга

агинк
```

Хотя token2 не изменялся в while loop, почему так происходит?

Comment: token и token2 - указатели, и после 'token2=token;' указывают на одну и ту же память. А вы изменяете token[i].

Comment: И как это можно исправить?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю зачем вам token2 и зачем вы инвертируете token, для поиска палиндрома достаточно проверять, что token[i]==token[j]; если не выполняется, значит это не палиндром

Comment: token2 мне нужен будет чтобы проверить через strcmp() два слова, один наоборот и один оригинал, token2 хочу использовать как оригинал, а token слово после инвертировании. Палиндром это когда слово написанное наоборот выходит то же слово. К примеру: мадам, Ана, и тд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[80]; int i, j, temp;
    const char s[] = " \n";
    char *token;
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    token = strtok(str, s);
    while (token != NULL) {

        i = 0;
        j = strlen(token) - 1;
        bool palindrome = true;
        while (i < j) {
            if (tolower(token[i]) != tolower(token[j])) {
                palindrome = false;
                break;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        if (palindrome) {
            printf("\n%s", token);
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: После последней правки всё работает как надо, спасибо, понял ошибку.